# Twitter Stream Filter By Location

Tags: filter, twitter, location, twitter-streaming-api

Is it possible for Twitter Stream API to filter tweets by the location field? As you can see in the sample JSON entry below that there is "location":"philippines" field - value. Now, what I wanted is to just filter tweets coming from that location through the location field. But don't get me wrong. I am not talking about GEO-tag filter.

Is this possible?

```
{"geo":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"truncated":false,"text":"RT @BreakingNewsPH: Typhoon hits Taiwan after pummeling Philippines: Typhoon Nanmadol slammed into\u2026 http:\/\/t.co\/rF3jbVU #breakingnews","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted":false,"retweet_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"breakingnews","indices":[120,133]}],"urls":[{"indices":[100,119],"display_url":"goo.gl\/fb\/JVdpj","expanded_url":"http:\/\/goo.gl\/fb\/JVdpj","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/rF3jbVU"}],"user_mentions":[{"indices":[3,18],"name":"Breaking News PH","screen_name":"BreakingNewsPH","id":190144401,"id_str":"190144401"}]},"coordinates":null,"retweeted_status":{"geo":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"truncated":false,"text":"Typhoon hits Taiwan after pummeling Philippines: Typhoon Nanmadol slammed into\u2026 http:\/\/t.co\/rF3jbVU #breakingnews","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted":false,"retweet_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"breakingnews","indices":[100,113]}],"urls":[{"indices":[80,99],"display_url":"goo.gl\/fb\/JVdpj","expanded_url":"http:\/\/goo.gl\/fb\/JVdpj","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/rF3jbVU"}],"user_mentions":[]},"coordinates":null,"place":null,"source":"\u003Ca href=\"http:\/\/www.google.com\/support\/youtube\/bin\/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164577\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003EGoogle\u003C\/a\u003E","created_at":"Mon Aug 29 04:16:31 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"user":{"listed_count":19,"favourites_count":0,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"252429","location":"Philippines","profile_background_tile":false,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"2FC2EF","description":"Follow us to receive round-the-clock Philippine Breaking News updates directly on your Twitter account!","default_profile_image":false,"default_profile":false,"verified":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"181A1E","notifications":null,"time_zone":"Hong Kong","created_at":"Mon Sep 13 05:14:02 +0000 2010","followers_count":804,"following":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme9\/bg.gif","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1130204413\/breakingnewsph-logo-small_normal.png","show_all_inline_media":false,"follow_request_sent":null,"geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"1A1B1F","protected":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme9\/bg.gif","url":"http:\/\/www.breakingnews.ph","screen_name":"BreakingNewsPH","name":"Breaking News PH","friends_count":210,"profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1130204413\/breakingnewsph-logo-small_normal.png","id":190144401,"id_str":"190144401","is_translator":false,"statuses_count":51981,"utc_offset":28800,"profile_text_color":"666666"},"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"favorited":false,"id":108030240370073602,"possibly_sensitive":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id_str":"108030240370073602"},"place":null,"source":"web","created_at":"Mon Aug 29 04:23:44 +0000 2011","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"user":{"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":1,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"FFF7CC","location":"cabuyao,Laguna PHILIPINES","profile_background_tile":false,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"FF0000","description":"Prudence keeps life safe, but it does not often make it happy.","default_profile_image":false,"default_profile":false,"verified":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"F2E195","notifications":null,"time_zone":"Alaska","created_at":"Sun Nov 14 09:15:11 +0000 2010","followers_count":32,"following":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/188170056\/Picture_276.jpg","profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a2.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1423110432\/271010_220561634650699_100000905924979_647505_1229915_n_normal.jpg","show_all_inline_media":true,"follow_request_sent":null,"geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"BADFCD","protected":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/188170056\/Picture_276.jpg","url":null,"screen_name":"emerlyn14","name":"Emerlyn Cantalejo","friends_count":215,"profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1423110432\/271010_220561634650699_100000905924979_647505_1229915_n_normal.jpg","id":215568114,"id_str":"215568114","is_translator":false,"statuses_count":270,"utc_offset":-32400,"profile_text_color":"0C3E53"},"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"favorited":false,"id":108032058986729472,"possibly_sensitive":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id_str":"108032058986729472"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well..you can't do it with the twitter api..twitter don't filter the location field only geotag..if you want filter location you must write a filter for filtering the location in the json respnse..it's really inefficient, you will lose a lot twitts because you only receive less 10% public status:

statuses/sample

Returns a random sample of all public statuses. The default access level, ‘Spritzer’ provides a small proportion of the Firehose, very roughly, 1% of all public statuses. The “Gardenhose” access level provides a proportion more suitable for data mining and research applications that desire a larger proportion to be statistically significant sample. Currently Gardenhose returns, very roughly, 10% of all public statuses. Note that these proportions are subject to unannounced adjustment as traffic volume varies.

and you can read too:

statuses/firehose

Returns all public statuses. The Firehose is not a generally available resource. Few applications require this level of access. Creative use of a combination of other resources and various access levels can satisfy nearly every application use case.

so..you only has 2 options..1) filter your entire country using the locations filter or 2) receive only 1% entire public statuses and filter it, maybe read it can help you:

bye and happy coding

Answer (score 8):

Check the twitter streaming api at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#locations

> **locations**
>
> Specifies a set of bounding boxes to track. Only tweets that are both
>   created using the Geotagging API and are placed from within a tracked
>   bounding box will be included in the stream – the user’s location
>   field is not used to filter tweets (e.g. if a user has their location
>   set to “San Francisco”, but the tweet was not created using the
>   Geotagging API and has no geo element, it will not be included in the
>   stream). Bounding boxes are specified as a comma separate list of
>   longitude/latitude pairs, with the first pair denoting the southwest
>   corner of the box. For example locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8
>   would track tweets from the San Francisco area. Multiple bounding
>   boxes may be specified by concatenating latitude/longitude pairs, for
>   example: locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41 would track
>   tweets from San Francisco and New York City.
>
> Just as with the track parameter, queries are subject to Track
>   Limitations, described in Track Limiting and subject to access roles,
>   described in the statuses/filter method. Both the number and size of
>   bounding boxes is limited. Bounding boxes can be up to 360 degrees
>   longitude by 180 degrees latitude, and you may specify up to 25
>   bounding boxes. A box of 360-degrees by 180-degrees will cover the
>   whole earth. Higher access levels provide additional bounding boxes.
>
> Bounding boxes are logical ORs. A locations parameter may be combined
>   with track parameters, but note that all terms are logically ORd, so
>   the query string
>   track=twitter&amp;locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8 would match
>   any tweets containing the term Twitter (even non-geo tweets) OR coming
>   from the San Francisco area.
>
> Values: longitude/latitude pairs, separated by commas. The first pair
>   specifies the southwest corner of the box. Methods: statuses/filter
>
> Example:  Create a file called ‘locations’ that contains, excluding
>   the quotation marks, the phrase:
>   “locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41” then execute:
>
> ```
> curl -d @locations https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json
> -uAnyTwitterUser:Password.
> ```
>
> You will receive all geo tagged tweets from the San Francisco and New
>   York City area.